# Как можно перевести деньги paypal api?

Tags: paypal

Как можно перевести средства с одного пользователя другому с помощью paypal api? Просто что-то в документации не могу найти =(

Answer (score 1):

Ответ: научиться задавать Гуглу правильные вопросы.

По запросу

> *paypal api transfer money between accounts*

вылезает куча тематически-правильных ссылок с детальными описаниями процессов. Например:

- [Introducing Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)
- [Pay API Operation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/)
- [How to send money to any paypal account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559808/how-to-send-money-to-any-paypal-account) [SO на англ.]
- [How do I transfer money from one account to the other using PayPal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985281/how-do-i-transfer-money-from-one-account-to-the-other-using-paypal) [SO на англ.]